# HERE Routing API - How to use publicTransportTimeTable mode with multiple waypoints using calculate route resource?

Tags: here-api

I'm using calculateroute resource to calculate a route between multiple waypoints.

> [https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}&waypoint0=-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;0&waypoint1=-25.4392733,-49.2722581;;1&waypoint2=-25.4367652,-49.2833011;;2&waypoint3=-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;3&waypoint4=-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;4&waypoint5=-25.4392733,-49.2722581;;5&departure=2019-09-09T07:10:00-03:00&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled;motorway:0&improveFor=distance&language=pt-br&representation=navigation&metricSystem=metric&vehicletype=diesel,5.5](https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=%7BAPP_ID%7D&app_code=%7BAPP_CODE%7D&waypoint0=-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;0&waypoint1=-25.4392733,-49.2722581;;1&waypoint2=-25.4367652,-49.2833011;;2&waypoint3=-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;3&waypoint4=-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;4&waypoint5=-25.4392733,-49.2722581;;5&departure=2019-09-09T07:10:00-03:00&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled;motorway:0&improveFor=distance&language=pt-br&representation=navigation&metricSystem=metric&vehicletype=diesel,5.5)

I was using **departure** parameter to set the initial date of the route, but now, instead of departure, I need to use arrival time in some cases. I was using car mode, but as **arrival** parameter requires **publicTransportTimeTable**, I set it this way.

> https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?...&mode=fastest;publicTransportTimeTable;motorway:0..

Then the return was this error message: ***"Time Table Transit Routing is only supported for two StopOver waypoints"***, then I set the waypoint0 and waypoint5 as stopOver and the rest as passThrough, and yet, I receive the same error.

**GET REQUEST**

> [https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}&waypoint0=stopOver!-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;0&waypoint1=passThrough!-25.4392733,-49.2722581;;1&waypoint2=passThrough!-25.4367652,-49.2833011;;2&waypoint3=passThrough!-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;3&waypoint4=passThrough!-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;4&waypoint5=stopOver!-25.4392733,-49.2722581;;5&arrival=2019-09-09T07:10:00-03:00&mode=fastest;publicTransportTimeTable;motorway:0&improveFor=distance&language=pt-br&representation=navigation&metricSystem=metric&vehicletype=diesel,5.5](https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=%7BAPP_ID%7D&app_code=%7BAPP_CODE%7D&waypoint0=stopOver!-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;0&waypoint1=passThrough!-25.4392733,-49.2722581;;1&waypoint2=passThrough!-25.4367652,-49.2833011;;2&waypoint3=passThrough!-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;3&waypoint4=passThrough!-25.4327193,-49.2806026;;4&waypoint5=stopOver!-25.4392733,-49.2722581;;5&arrival=2019-09-09T07:10:00-03:00&mode=fastest;publicTransportTimeTable;motorway:0&improveFor=distance&language=pt-br&representation=navigation&metricSystem=metric&vehicletype=diesel,5.5)

**RETURN**

```
{
    "_type": "ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
    "type": "ApplicationError",
    "subtype": "InvalidInputData",
    "details": "Time Table Transit Routing is only supported for two StopOver waypoints",
    "additionalData": [
        {
            "key": "waypoint",
            "value": ""
        }
    ],
    "metaInfo": {
        "timestamp": "2019-09-10T13:40:27Z",
        "mapVersion": "8.30.99.156",
        "moduleVersion": "7.2.201935-5091",
        "interfaceVersion": "2.6.68",
        "availableMapVersion": [
            "8.30.99.156"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stated in the documentation, you can only use the `arrival` parameter when `mode` is set to `publicTransportTimeTable`. And this type of routing currently supports only two stopover waypoints (`waypoint0` and `waypoint1`) and no passthrough waypoints.